# Magento2 minify Javascript google page speed insights

Tags: magento2, google-pagespeed

While I have no different settings for Desktop and mobile,but google page speed insights pass the test for desktop as javascript minified, but fails for all JS files for mobile test as not minified.

Does anyone faced similar issue, what could be reason for this?